# Solving stochastic maximum bipartite matching problem

Tags: matching, max, graph-algorithm, bipartite, stochastic

I have faced the following problem:

- there are two disjoint sets, `A` and `B`
- for each pair of elements (`a`, `b`) (`a` belongs to set `A`, where `b` belongs to set `B`) there a probability `pij` is known in advance. It represents the probability (certainty level) that `a` matches `b`, or in other words, how closely `a` matches `b` (and vice-versa, because `pij` == `pji`).
- I have to find a matching with the highest probability/certainty and find out pairs (`a`, `b`) which describe the matching
- every element must be matched / paired with another from the other set exactly once (like in the standard bipartite matching problem)
- if possible, I would like to compute a number which approximately expresses the uncertainty level for the obtained matching (let's say that 0 represents random guess and 1 represents certainty)

A simple practical example in which such algorithm is required is described below (this is not actually the problem I am solving!):

- two people are asked to write letters
  a - z on a piece of paper
- for each pair of letters (`a`, `b`) we run a pattern matcher to determine the probability that letter `a` written by person `A` represents letter `b` wrote by person `B`. This gives us the
  probability matrix which expresses some kind of similarity correlation
  for each pair of letters (`a`, `b`)
- for each letter that person `A` wrote,
  we need to find the corresponding
  letter written by person `B`

**Current approach:**
I am wondering if I could just assign weights which are proportional to the logarithm of certainty level / probability that element `a` from set `A` matches element `b` from set `B` and then run maximum weighted bipartite matching to find the maximum sum. The logarithm is because I want to maximize the total probability of multiple matching, and since single matches (represented as pairs of matched elements `a` - `b`) form a chain of events, which is a product of probabilities, by taking the logarithm we converts this to a sum of probabilities, which is then easily maximized using an algorithm for weighted bipartite matching, such as Hungarian algorithm. But I somehow doubt this approach would ensure the best matching in terms of statistical expected maximum.

After searching a bit, the closest problem I found was a two-stage stochastic maximum weighted matching problem, which is NP-hard, but I actually need some kind of "one-stage" stochastic maximum weighted matching problem.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if you can use MaxFlow/MinCut.  I can't prove it's optimal at the moment, but your problem may be NP-hard anyway.  You can use MF/MC to find a perfect matching when you have a bipartite graph with V=(A,B) by creating a source connected to all nodes in A with a weight of 1 and a sink connected to all nodes in B with weight 1.  I'm proposing you make the weights of edges that cross from A to B be the probabilities you mentioned above.  What do you think?

Comment: I found another approach in the meanwhile. There is an algorithm called Hungarian algorithm that solves the assignment problem. Since this algorithm maximizes the sum of probabilities, but I am actually interested in their product (since I have a chain of "events"), I could apply the logarithm function to then. So my current approach is as follows: 1) build a probability matrix for matching probabilities in bipartite graph; 2) take a natural logarithm of every element of the matrix; 3) run Hungarian algorithm to maximize the probability of all matchings. How does this sounds?